# Not Getting Correct Answer for sine & cosine in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, trigonometry

I am going through some of my old C++ school assignments and re-doing them using Python. I am now re-doing an assignment where we had to approximate sin() and cos(). I am using the same math I used in the C++ version updated to work in Python but the answers I am getting are quite different. I was wondering if there was some small difference I am not aware of that is causing the discrepancy. I have been using 3.14 as my input.

```
import math

def sin(x):
    for n in range(4):
        ans = 0
        ans += (math.pow(-1, n)/math.factorial(2 * n + 1)) * math.pow(x, 2 * n + 1)
    print ans

def cos(x):
        for n in range(4):
                ans = 0
                ans += (math.pow(-1, n)/math.factorial(2 * n)) * math.pow(x, 2 * n)
        print ans

while True:
    try:
        x = float(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was not a valid number.  Try again..."

sin(x)
cos(x)
```

I think it's also worth noting I get a different answer if I use `math.pow(-1, n)` vs. `-1**n`.

Comment: `-1**n` groups as `-(1**n)`.  Write `(-1)**n` if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting `ans = 0` inside your loop, and thus you are printing one term instead of the sum. Try:

```
def sin(x):
    ans = 0
    for n in range(4):
        ans += (math.pow(-1, n)/math.factorial(2*n + 1)) * math.pow(x, 2*n + 1)
    print ans
```

etc. This seems to produce correct results.

Also, it makes more sense for functions to *return* values rather than just print them:

```
def sin(x, terms=4):
    ans = 0
    for n in range(terms):
        ans += (math.pow(-1, n)/math.factorial(2*n + 1)) * math.pow(x, 2*n + 1)
    return ans
```

or:

```
def sin(x, terms=4):
    return sum(
            (-1.)**n / math.factorial(2*n + 1) * math.pow(x, 2*n + 1)
        for n in range(terms))
```

Then you would `print sin(x)` at the end of the script.